# How not to erase data from a file during serialization?

Tags: c#

Good evening,

I realize an application currently using the C # language and I had to resort to serialization using XmlSerializer.

I had to be able to save a list in an xml file. It was then necessary that I could recover the data of this file to be able to recover the list. I managed to do all this and here is my code:

To save the list:

```cs
Stream stream = File.OpenWrite(chemin);
           XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Utilisateur>));
           xmlSer.Serialize(stream,listeUtilisateurs);
           stream.Close();
```

To retrieve the list:

```cs
Stream stream = File.OpenRead(chemin);
            XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Utilisateur>));
            List<Utilisateur> listrecuperee = (List<Utilisateur>)xmlSer.Deserialize(stream);
            listeUtilisateurs = listrecuperee;
            stream.Close();
```

However, the problem is that every time I save the list, the data that was before it go away, I want to keep it, I actually want it to write after the file. Would you have a solution please? Cordially.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will result in a file which has two XML documents. When you look at the whole content of the file, it will not be a valid XML document anymore. Why do you not create a new file?

Comment: The docs clearly state: *"For an existing file, it does not append the new text to the existing text. Instead, it overwrites the existing characters with the new characters."*: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openwrite  You can use a `FileStream` to control this behavior: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream  Though as mentioned in a comment above, how do you plan to structure your data?  Perhaps you can read the current XML into a data structure, modify the data, and then re-output everything?  Or consider using a database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can do what you want.

Code to serialize to the same file:

```
var xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Utilisateur>));

var xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
    Indent = true // need only for pretty print
};

bool append = File.Exists("test.txt");

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter("test.txt", append))
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(streamWriter, xmlWriterSettings))
{
    xmlSer.Serialize(xmlWriter, listeUtilisateurs);
    streamWriter.WriteLine(); // need only for pretty print
}
```

Code for reading a set of data:

```
int orderNumber = 2; // for example, read the second data collection in order

var xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
};

using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("test.txt", xmlReaderSettings))
{
    int count = 0;
    while (reader.ReadToFollowing("ArrayOfUtilisateur"))
    {
        count++;
        if (count == orderNumber)
            break;
    }
    var list = (List<Utilisateur>)xmlSer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Of course, you need to add the necessary checks when reading.

This way of using a single file is pretty ugly, though it works. Therefore, consider other options for saving your data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is true that it is not very ergonomic. I basically wanted to use SQLite to update but I just do not know how to save lists in a database. For int, string etc .. it's easy but for a list ...

Comment: @Ush_63 - In your question there is no word about the database. I gave you a perfectly workable answer.

Comment: @Ush_63 - If you need to save the list to a database, then ask about it. Create new post.

Comment: That's what I'm going to do, thanks, because I started to turn to the SQLite solution this morning.